# "System.IO.IOException: Function not implemented" error while running dotnet docker compose project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, kestrel-http-server

I have a dotnet app, which I am trying to run using Docker-Compose file. The container is running on **"Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"**.

In the **Program.cs** file, when I run the this code below,

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
            {
                // gRPC endpoint listening on port 5001.
                // rest endpoint listening on port 80
            });

            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

it is giving following error.

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Function not implemented
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEventsIfNotDisposed()
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.set_EnableRaisingEvents(Boolean value)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.TryEnableFileSystemWatcher()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.PhysicalFilesWatcher.CreateFileChangeToken(String filter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider.Watch(String filter)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.<.ctor>b__1_0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider..ctor(FileConfigurationSource source)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationSource.Build(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at tvod_core.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/app-name/Program.cs:line 15
qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
```

I am running this application on **Apple M1**. Below are docker versions,

```
>>> docker -v
Docker version 23.0.5, build bc4487a
>>> docker-compose -v
WARNING: Compose V1 is no longer supported and will be removed from Docker Desktop in an upcoming release. See https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-v1-eol/
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
```

**I tried:**
I am new to dotnet, but I think issue seems to be with **FileSystemWatcher** class on Linux-based systems like Debian GNU/Linux which might have limited functionality and doesn't support all the features available on Windows. So, I tried Disabling file system event monitoring in Docker, but no luck.

```
         webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
            {
                if (!RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
                {
                    var kestrelConfiguration = context.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel");
                    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
                    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Reload configuration on changes has not been implemented on M1 Mac.

The same has been tracked here. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38876

As a workaround, we have to add this ENV flag to disable FileSystemWatcher

> ASPNETCORE_hostBuilder__reloadConfigOnChange=false

Comment: it works. since I am using docker compose file I had to add same config under,
environment:
      ASPNETCORE_hostBuilder__reloadConfigOnChange: "false"